# Find the average of Quantity for last 30 days and 60 days in pandas groupby

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, aggregate, average

The code to create the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

z = pd.DataFrame({'VENDOR':['A','A','A','A','B','B'],
                  'PO_DATE':['2020-12-16','2020-12-02','2020-11-23','2020-11-09','2020-12-16','2020-11-02'],
                  'PO_QTY':[18,5,77,6,20,5]})
z['PO_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(z['PO_DATE'])
z = z.sort_values(['VENDOR','PO_DATE']).reset_index(drop=True)
 
z1 = z.groupby(['VENDOR']).agg({'PO_DATE':'last'}).rename(columns = {'PO_DATE':'MAX_PO_DATE'})
z2 = pd.merge(z,z1, on = 'VENDOR')
z2['DURATION'] = (z2['MAX_PO_DATE'] - z2['PO_DATE']).dt.days
```

The Dataframe looks like this.

[image]

This dataframe is grouped on VENDOR and PO_DATE level.

I have created the MAX_PO_DATE and DURATION (By taking the difference of MAX_PO_DATE and PO_DATE).

I need to find the average of PO_QTY for the last 30 days and last 60 days for each record.

[image]

For Example:

In the first record, the date difference between 1st and 4th record is 37 but for 1st and 3rd record, it is 23 which is less than 30 days, so the AVG_PO_QTY_30_DAYS is the average of PO_QTY for the first 3 records of the same vendor which is (6+77+5)/3.

For 60 days, it will be (6+77+5+18)/4 since the date difference from 1st to 4th record is less than 60 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

In first place, I have changed your code because I need to work with a descending order in order to apply rolling windows easily

```py
import pandas as pd

z = pd.DataFrame({'VENDOR':['A','A','A','A','B','B'],
                  'PO_DATE':['2020-12-16','2020-12-02','2020-11-23','2020-11-09','2020-12-16','2020-11-02'],
                  'PO_QTY':[18,5,77,6,20,5]})
z['PO_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(z['PO_DATE'])
z["MAX_PO_DATE"] = z.groupby(['VENDOR'])["PO_DATE"].transform("max")
z['DURATION'] = (z['MAX_PO_DATE'] - z['PO_DATE']).dt.days

#sort descending to use window correctly
z = z.sort_values(['VENDOR','PO_DATE'],ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

After that, i can apply moving windows based on time if i set the date as index.

```py
df = z # not necessary but i like the df name

last_30_df = df.set_index("PO_DATE").groupby("VENDOR")["PO_QTY"].rolling("30d").mean().reset_index()
last_30_df.rename(columns={"PO_QTY": "AVG_PO_QTY_30_DAYS"}, inplace=True)

last_60_df = df.set_index("PO_DATE").groupby("VENDOR")["PO_QTY"].rolling("60d").mean().reset_index()
last_60_df.rename(columns={"PO_QTY": "AVG_PO_QTY_60_DAYS"}, inplace=True)

df = df.merge(last_30_df,  how='left', left_on=['VENDOR','PO_DATE'], right_on = ['VENDOR','PO_DATE'])
df = df.merge(last_60_df,  how='left', left_on=['VENDOR','PO_DATE'], right_on = ['VENDOR','PO_DATE'])

df = df.sort_values(['VENDOR','PO_DATE']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Finally we got this:
[image]

Comment: This only gives the average value per vendor. I needed it for each transaction. I have edited the question for better clarification. Thanks :)

Comment: I think that i have a result, check it out

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot. I haven't heard about the rolling function before. :)